# Passing Data from Service to Component

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

Before someone mark this as duplicate Below are the links that I tried and failed

[Angular 2 - passing data from service to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775359/angular-2-passing-data-from-service-to-component)

[How to subscribe to an event on a service in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131490/how-to-subscribe-to-an-event-on-a-service-in-angular2)

Scenario
I want to sent data from my ng2 service to component and the data is being loaded from an API using ng2 HTTP

Below is the dummy code

MyService

```
@Output() event_callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

getUserDetails(id)
{
    var user_data;
    this.loadRemoteUrl('getUserdata?user_id=' + id).subscribe(
        data => { user_data = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => {
            console.log('Inside My Service');
            this.user_data = user_data;
            this.event_callback.emit(this.user_data);
        }
    );
}
```

MyComponent

```
constructor(private http:Http, private myService: MyService) 
{
    var userDetails;
    myService.event_callback.subscribe(
        data => this.callbackFunction()
    );
}

callbackFunction()
{
    console.log("Inside MyComponent")
}
```

Console Log

```
Inside My Service
```

The HTTP request is returning data properly which I tried dumping before emit and it worked but problem is I am unable to access data in my component, I tried passing data,now I am just some logging messages to identify flow but still unable to see the log message from my component file.

What did I miss?

Comment: Can you make sure your component  subscribes to the service before getUserDetails is called ?

Comment: Where are you calling `getUserDetails`? From another component? Also note that you don't need to put an @Output annotation on a service

Comment: It's being called from another method from the component... @rob

Comment: @Milad Yes, I am sure that component subscribes when the `getUserDetails()` method is called...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case instead of @Output i recommend use observable Subject.

In your service, insted of:

```
@Output() event_callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Create new observable source and stream (Remember to import Subject from "rxjs/Subject"):

```
private eventCallback = new Subject<string>(); // Source
eventCallback$ = this.eventCallback.asObservable(); // Stream
```

Insted of:

```
this.event_callback.emit(this.user_data);
```

Send message by:

```
this.eventCallback.next(this.user_data);
```

And then, in your component:

```
myService.eventCallback$.subscribe(data => {
    this.callbackFunction();
});
```

See: [working example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hhc6lTSwGQWP3zq2Ttlu?p=preview)

Read more about this solution:
[Angular.io - Communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Comment: I already tried that didn't work, But as per my knowledge they both work in the same way and `emit` is in latest Angular, where as  `next` is in older version, thanks for the efforts...

Comment: @AkshayKhale I have added working example on plunker, check it out: https://plnkr.co/edit/Hhc6lTSwGQWP3zq2Ttlu?p=preview

Comment: @jarek Thank you for the plunkr helped me out a ton! One little issue with it. private eventCallback: Subject<any[]> = new Subject<any>(); Should be private eventCallback: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); *removed the array syntax* if you want to pass just a string.